# Trigonometry (Law of Cosines)

Tags: trigonometry

In case of right angled triangles, $C^2 = A^2 +B^2 - 2AB \cos(\Psi)$ is shortened to $C^2 = A^2 +B^2$ because the cosine of the angle "$\Psi$" which is $90^\circ$ is equal to $0$. But how is its cosine equal to $0$.

[image: wemphasized text]

Comment: It is $$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$ look at the graph of $$f(x)=\cos(x)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cos/introductions/Cos/ShowAll.html

Answer (score 1):

In a right-angled triangle of hypotenuse $1$, each acute angle's cosine is the length of its adjacent side. If one of these angles is almost a right angle, the triangle will be almost isosceles, with only a very small third angle, opposite the side we can consider the base. It is this side that is adjacent to the acute angle that's almost a right angle, so the cosine of that angle is small.

Answer (score 1):

In elementary geometry, when the angle between two lines is $\psi$, $\cos  \psi$ is the factor of the orthogonal projection of one line onto the other, i.e. the length of a segment on one line is multiplied by this factor when projected onto the other line. Obviously, if the lines are orthogonal, all points of the first line are projected onto the same point of the other line, so that this factor is $0$.